# Gnuplot Candlesticks and boxwidth

Tags: gnuplot, financial, candlestick-chart

Been working with candlesticks on real financial data.   It works great unless I have gaps in the data, which there are plenty with historical financial data.

I have had "set boxwidth 1 relative" and it works ok, it gives me a proper "width" of the candlestick in most cases.  But if there is no data between 2 points the candlestick will become fatter, i.e. it extends right to fill that gap.   The visual is horrible, the extension to the right is really bad.

I have tried playing with set boxwidth x absolute, but I cannot come to terms in how it is displaying.  I have narrowed it down to `set boxwidth 37500 absolute` and have no idea why that number works, even though it has even worse problems then the set boxwidth 1 relative.

The first image is what it looks like using `set boxwidth 37500 absolute`.  There the dates goes from 01/31/13, 02/01/13, 02/03/13, 02/04/13, 02/05/13.   There is no 02/02/13:

[image]

The absolute shows a proper gap between 02/01 and 02/02 but 02/03 and 02/04 overlap for reasons I cannot explain.

The second image uses set boxwidth 1 relative.   This has it mostly the way I want it.  The candlesticks are adjacent and mostly right.   But the gap on 02/02/13 it fattens to the right.  There is also a gap on 02/09/13 where it also fattens, or possibly the 2 on either side extend to fill the gap I do not know.

[image]

How can I configure this so that all the candlesticks are the same width adjacent and gaps in the data are empty?

I googled this like crazy and no one talks about it.  The few examples of candlesticks that I have found do not use "dates" but integers, totally worthless.   Candlestick charts require dates per the manual.

Running Gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0 on Windows 7.

Thank you

PS: I should have added data here goes.

`basic.csv`:

```
2013-01-15 00:00:00,93.879000,93.949000,92.874000,93.078000
2013-01-16 00:00:00,93.079000,93.672000,92.458000,92.800000
2013-01-17 00:00:00,92.799000,95.011000,92.629000,94.616000
2013-01-18 00:00:00,94.617000,94.872000,94.157000,94.662000
2013-01-20 17:00:00,94.649000,94.820000,93.965000,94.155000
2013-01-21 00:00:00,94.159000,94.938000,93.726000,94.009000
2013-01-22 00:00:00,94.011000,94.284000,93.147000,93.231000
2013-01-23 00:00:00,93.229000,94.024000,92.793000,93.649000
2013-01-24 00:00:00,93.650000,94.715000,93.559000,94.489000
2013-01-25 00:00:00,94.490000,95.083000,94.472000,94.749000
2013-01-27 17:00:00,94.819000,95.007000,94.652000,94.834000
2013-01-28 00:00:00,94.835000,94.968000,94.082000,94.809000
2013-01-29 00:00:00,94.803000,95.330000,94.370000,95.248000
2013-01-30 00:00:00,95.245000,95.450000,94.255000,94.365000
2013-01-31 00:00:00,94.372000,95.799000,94.328000,95.714000
2013-02-01 00:00:00,95.715000,96.718000,95.457000,96.597000
2013-02-03 17:00:00,96.716000,96.777000,96.370000,96.572000
2013-02-04 00:00:00,96.574000,97.064000,95.968000,96.044000
2013-02-05 00:00:00,96.043000,97.426000,95.945000,97.131000
2013-02-06 00:00:00,97.133000,97.284000,96.092000,96.395000
2013-02-07 00:00:00,96.396000,97.023000,95.813000,96.145000
2013-02-08 00:00:00,96.146000,96.182000,95.124000,95.625000
2013-02-10 17:00:00,95.623000,95.744000,95.210000,95.339000
2013-02-11 00:00:00,95.336000,96.877000,95.168000,96.537000
2013-02-12 00:00:00,96.536000,96.719000,95.776000,96.214000
2013-02-13 00:00:00,96.216000,96.890000,96.114000,96.775000
2013-02-14 00:00:00,96.771000,96.964000,95.609000,95.621000
2013-02-15 00:00:00,95.622000,96.676000,95.521000,96.351000
```

`absolute.plt`:

```
reset

set border linecolor rgbcolor "yellow"
set key textcolor rgbcolor "white"

set obj 1 rectangle behind from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1
set obj 1 fillstyle solid 1.0 fillcolor rgbcolor "black"

set xdata time
set timefmt"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["2013-01-15 00:00:00":"2013-02-15 23:59:59"]

set yrange [*:*]
set datafile separator ","

set palette defined (-1 'red', 1 'green')
set cbrange [-1:1]
unset colorbox

set style fill solid noborder
set boxwidth 37500 absolute

set title "AUDJPY" textcolor rgbcolor "white"
plot 'basic.csv' using 1:2:4:3:5:($5 < $2 ? -1 : 1) with candlesticks palette
```

`relative.plt`:

```
reset

set border linecolor rgbcolor "yellow"
set key textcolor rgbcolor "white"

set obj 1 rectangle behind from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1
set obj 1 fillstyle solid 1.0 fillcolor rgbcolor "black"

set xdata time
set timefmt"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["2013-01-15 00:00:00":"2013-02-15 23:59:59"]

set yrange [*:*]
set datafile separator ","

set palette defined (-1 'red', 1 'green')
set cbrange [-1:1]
unset colorbox

set style fill solid noborder
set boxwidth 1 relative

set title "AUDJPY" textcolor rgbcolor "white"
plot 'basic.csv' using 1:2:4:3:5:($5 < $2 ? -1 : 1) with candlesticks palette
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `set boxwidth absolute`, the width is given in units of the x-axis, which in the case of dates is seconds. So, a width of `37500` is 10 hours.

You could also use an explicit width in the 6th column, and switch to -2 to get an automatic box width for certain columns. That however would require you to manipulate your data file by hand.

Another point: Is it essential for you to include the hours in some data points? This is what narrows the distance of some adjacent points. You could ignore the hours, which would give you a point distance of minimum one day. To strip the hours, use `strptime` in the `using` statement:

```
reset

set border linecolor rgbcolor "yellow"
set key textcolor rgbcolor "white"

set obj 1 rectangle behind from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1
set obj 1 fillstyle solid 1.0 fillcolor rgbcolor "black"

set xdata time
set timefmt"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["2013-01-15 00:00:00":"2013-02-15 23:59:59"]

set yrange [*:*]
set datafile separator ","

set palette defined (-1 'red', 1 'green')
set cbrange [-1:1]
unset colorbox

set style fill solid noborder
set boxwidth 60000 absolute

set title "AUDJPY" textcolor rgbcolor "white"
plot 'basic.csv' using (strptime('%Y-%m-%d', strcol(1))):2:4:3:5:($5 < $2 ? -1 : 1) with candlesticks palette
```

Result with 4.6.0:

[image]

Comment: Thank you I looked over the docs and could not ascertain it was in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
Another script,

from candlestick_chart import Candle, Chart

# Add some candles
candles = [
    Candle(133.520004, 133.610001, 126.760002, 129.410004),
    Candle(128.889999, 131.740005, 128.429993, 131.009995),
    Candle(127.720001, 131.050003, 126.379997, 126.599998),
    Candle(128.360001, 131.630005, 127.860001, 130.919998),
    Candle(132.429993, 132.630005, 130.229996, 132.050003),
]

# Create and display the chart
# Optional keyword arguments: title, width, height
chart = Chart(candles, title="Optional title")

# Set the chart title
chart.set_name("BTC/USDT")

# Set customs colors
chart.set_bear_color(1, 205, 254)
chart.set_bull_color(255, 107, 153)
chart.set_vol_bull_color(1, 205, 254)
chart.set_vol_bear_color(255, 107, 153)

# Set custom labels (empty string => label not displayed)
chart.set_label("highest", "ATH")
chart.set_label("lowest", "ATL")
chart.set_label("average", "")
chart.set_label("volume", "")

# Volume pane settings
chart.set_volume_pane_height(6)
chart.set_volume_pane_enabled(False)

# And, it is also responsive!
new_width = 200
new_height = 150
chart.update_size(new_width, new_height)

# By the way, did you know that you can add more candles in real-time?
chart.update_candles(candles[:3])
# Or completely replace current candles `enter code here`
chart.update_candles(candles[:3], reset=True)

chart.draw()
```

Comment: The question is tagged "gnuplot". So, what does this answer have to do with gnuplot?